# React High Resolution Screenshot

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to take a high quality screen shot of a react component. I have tried using html2canvas and jsPDF, but the overall quality is quite poor. Just to be clear, I've tried converting a component with html2canvas, then converting that to a PDF using jsPDF.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
const printDocument = function() {
const input = document.getElementById('graph-id');
html2canvas(input, {
  scale: 2
})
  .then((canvas) => {

    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'landscape',
      format: [3000, 3000]
    }
    );
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10);
    // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
    pdf.save("download.pdf");

  })
```

}

In particular I'm trying to screenshot a graph that is generated with: https://danielcaldas.github.io/react-d3-graph/docs/. Wondering if there is a better way to generate a high quality pdf or image? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am also looking

Comment: No I didn't find a solution